# Microsoft Excel code running slow

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following code to list out the objects in a workbook into another workbook;

```
For Each ws In mainworkBook.Sheets
    
    For Each includedObjects In ws.Shapes

        outputBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i) = ws.Name
        outputBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i) = TypeName(includedObjects)
        outputBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i) = includedObjects.Name
        i = i + 1
        
    Next
        
Next
```

However, this takes 5 minutes to run with about 2500 objects listed. But this code that outputs to a CSV file only take a couple of seconds for the same results.

```
objFile.writeline "Sheet, Object Type, Object name"
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    For Each includedObjects In ws.Shapes
        objFile.writeline ws.Name & "," & TypeName(includedObjects) & "," & includedObjects.Name
    Next
Next
```

How can I improve the first code so it runs faster?

Comment: every time vba pierces the worksheet, the vba code slows down.  With large loops, this is very noticeable.  That is why Gary's Student suggested using an array that outputs to the worksheet.  That way the number of times the references to the worksheet range is kept to a minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be somewhat faster:

```
Dim arr(1 To 9999, 1 To 3) As String
Dim i As Long
i = 1
For Each ws In mainworkBook.Sheets
    For Each includedObjects In ws.Shapes
        arr(i, 1) = ws.Name
        arr(i, 2) = TypeName(includedObjects)
        arr(i, 3) = includedObjects.Name
        i = i + 1
    Next
Next

outputBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C9999") = arr
```

*(if the 9999 is not enough, make it larger)*

**NOTE:**

1. Because you are interested in speed, we use an "oversize" static array rather than a dynamic array.
2. The code only "touches" the Sheet one time.

Comment: I'm not interested in speed as such I was concerned that there was an error in my code slowing it down. I would much prefer a dynamic array as long as it is not too slow as I have no idea how many results could be returned and would not want to come back to the code to update it if the results would increase.